# How do I set the FallbackValue for a Binding on UIElement.Margin?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, syntax

Consider the following bit of code:

```
<UserControl x:Name=root>
....
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World" Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LeftButtonMargin}"/>
....
</UserControl>
```

Now, *what is the syntax for setting the `FallBackvalue` on the Binding?*
I've tried some different options already, but I cannot seem to find the correct syntax:

```
Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LeftButtonMargin, FallBackValue={}10,10,0,0}"
Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LeftButtonMargin, FallBackValue={}{10,10,0,0}}"
Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LeftButtonMargin, FallBackValue={}"10,10,0,0"}"
```

Or is this not possible at all? Basically, I need these values at design time...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hopefully works,

```
<UserControl.Resources>
 <Thickness x:Key="MyMargin" Bottom="5" Top="10">

 </Thickness>
<UserControl.Resources>


<TextBlock Text="Hello World" 
Margin="{Binding ...,FallBackValue={StaticResource MyMargin}}"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

More simple: use single quotes

```
Margin="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LeftButtonMargin, FallBackValue='10,10,0,0'}"
```

Comment: The accepted answer for multiple and different margins

Answer (score 2):

This is works for me:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Hello World">
        <TextBlock.Margin>
            <Binding ElementName="root" Path="LeftButtonMargin" FallbackValue="10, 10, 0, 0" />
        </TextBlock.Margin>
    </TextBlock>
```

but its rather big...