# How an I set a default Label value when binding its Content in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Label defined in XAML as follows:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
```

The problem is that the label is invisible in the XAML editor and I'd like it to have a default value there so that the editor accurately reflects what will show up at runtime.

Is there a way to give it a value in XAML which will show up in the editor, but then use the binding at runtime?

Comment: [What approaches are available to dummy design-time data in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889966/what-approaches-are-available-to-dummy-design-time-data-in-wpf)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default value at design time XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208665/default-value-at-design-time-xaml)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go

`FallbackValue` is the answer for the same

example

```xml
<Label Content="{Binding Name, FallbackValue=Default}"></Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

You also assign the default value to name of its viewmodel.cs file in its constructor

Comment: He's right, but he explain badly. He want to say that a default value can be set in the default constructor of the ViewModel, and it will be shown in the design mode.